# Empty Post request (.NetCore 3.1)

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-core, post

I upgraded my app to *****.net Core 3.1*****
And when I try to send a Post request by a  ***http client*** to my web App
The body of the message arrives empty at the destination.
when i was checking the Request in my web App, i saw that the `Request.ContentLenght` value is completely correct.

I realized that there are problems with this in .net core 3.1,
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

- i thought it may be a Buffering issue, but i didn't find implementaion of `EnableBuffering()` method.

> Here is my code:

Http Client who makes a post request for a web app:

```
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("test Data");
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

var response =  await myHttpClient.PostAsync(destUrl,httpContent);
```

Implementing a Post Request in My Web App:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    // Request.Body is empty.
}
```

Comment: Please check if you have already read request body in filter/middleware etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are receiving an empty string, it means that something else already read it. Since `Request.Body` is a stream, you have to seek to the beginning to read it again.

But first you need to call `EnableBufferring()`, because by default `Request.Body` can only be read only once. You can do it Startup.cs file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // be sure to add it before the other middleware
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
         context.Request.EnableBuffering();
         return next();
    });

    // everything else
}
```

Then you can read your `Request.Body`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    var rawMessage = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```